# moduleNameMapper stopped working when upgrading to ts-jest 23

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm working on a project with a custom webpack build. React, Typescript, Jest tests in typescript as well.

The tests have been working as expected for as long as I've been on the project. 
Yesterday however I upgraded `ts-jest` to the latest version (24.x or 23.x) and some of my mappings stopped working, jest itself has been on 24 for a while.

Anyone have a clue why this could happen? I've tried renaming the folder as it's in the `jest` folder and that seems odd to me (import from `jest/helpers/withProviders` confused me the first time is saw that). However it has been working fine for at least a year.

Also I believe that when the target of the mapping is missing it should throw warnings or errors? It doesns't seem to do that when I change any of the mappings to something invalid. **This did work on version 22!**

## Edit:

If it was not clear, my error is on the line where I import our mock located in `/jest/helpers/withProviders` in my codebase (which works perfectly fine in ts-jest@22).

here is my jest.config:

```
module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
      '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
    '\\.(css|less|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    '^jest[/](.+)': '<rootDir>/jest/$1',
    '^jest$': '<rootDir>/jest',
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+project-name-framework.*\\.js$': './jest/transform.js',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!@brand-name|@project-name)', '<rootDir>/src/utils/sso'],
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$',
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules', '/__tests__/__mocks__/', '<rootDir>/cypress/'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  testURL: 'http://localhost/some-brand-name',
  moduleDirectories: ['src', 'node_modules'],
  collectCoverage: false, // set this to true to show coverage reports
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/components/**',
    'src/containers/**',
    'src/pages/**',
    'src/utils/**',
    '!**/__snapshots__/**',
    '!**/__mocks__/**',
  ],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest/helpers/setup-tests.ts'],
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stopped working"? Do you get any errors that might be helpful?

Comment: @Teneff It was implied but maybe not clearly, as stated in my edit I'm importing files which are in my project, and working as expected in ts-jest@22

Comment: does that `'<rootDir>/jestt/$1',` contains a typo `jestt`, or you have an actual directory called `jestt` ?

Comment: Good eye, that error was added on purpose by me to see if it would trigger the config validation warning (which doesn't trigger after upgrading)